# Python Turtle has Stopped Listening

Tags: python-3.x, turtle-graphics

I want to make a drawing app that uses the WSAD keys to move the turtle, Q and E to raise and lower the pen, and I tried to add a dialog box so you can choose the color of the turtle, but after I change the color, the turtle won't respond to the WSAD keybindings. Can someone explain what is going on and how to fix this problem?

Here is the code:

```py
import turtle

#WSAD to move
def up():
    char.setheading(90)
    char.forward(10)

def down():
    char.setheading(270)
    char.forward(10)

def goLeft():
    char.setheading(180)
    char.forward(10)

def goRight():
    char.setheading(0)
    char.forward(10)


#Raises and Lowers the pen
def lowerPen():
    char.pendown()
def raisePen():
    char.penup()

#change colors
def color():
    data = turtle.simpledialog.askstring("Change Color", "Change Color to:")
    char.color(data)

#Char info
char = turtle.Turtle()
char.speed(0)

screen = turtle.Screen()
screen.title("Arrow Paint")

#Make Turtle Listen to Keystrokes.
turtle.listen()

#Keybindings
turtle.onkey(color, "c")
turtle.onkey(up, "w")
turtle.onkey(down, "s")
turtle.onkey(goLeft, "a")
turtle.onkey(goRight, "d")
turtle.onkey(raisePen, "q")
turtle.onkey(lowerPen, "e")


turtle.done()
```

Thank you in advance

Edit: I have also tried substituting the `turtle.simpledialog.askstring()` function with the `textinput()` function I found, and it still won't respond to the keybindings

Comment: The code only shows a dialog with a pointer on Linux. It doesn't do anything with key presses.

Comment: @codezombie What do you mean?

Comment: I mean the keyboard shortcuts don't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do:

```
turtle.listen()
```

you make your turtle window the *listener* for keyboard events.  But when you invoke:

```
 data = turtle.simpledialog.askstring("Change Color", "Change Color to:")
```

or `textinput()`, the window that pops up becomes the *listener* for keyboard events.  So when you're done with your user dialog window, call:

```
turtle.listen()
```

again afterward.  This should allow your turtle keyboard events to operate as before.  The revised code:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

# WSAD to move
def goUp():
    char.setheading(90)
    char.forward(10)

def goDown():
    char.setheading(270)
    char.forward(10)

def goLeft():
    char.setheading(180)
    char.forward(10)

def goRight():
    char.setheading(0)
    char.forward(10)

# Raise and Lowers the pen
def lowerPen():
    char.pendown()

def raisePen():
    char.penup()

# Change colors
def color():
    data = screen.textinput("Change Color", "Change Color to:")
    char.color(data)
    screen.listen()

screen = Screen()
screen.title("Arrow Paint")

# Char info
char = Turtle()
char.speed('fastest')

# Keybindings
screen.onkey(color, "c")

screen.onkey(goUp, "w")
screen.onkey(goDown, "s")
screen.onkey(goLeft, "a")
screen.onkey(goRight, "d")

screen.onkey(raisePen, "q")
screen.onkey(lowerPen, "e")

# Make Turtle Listen to Keystrokes.
screen.listen()

screen.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks @cdlane. Also, I fixed it by myself, but thank you for the answer. I liked your answer, as it was very informative. Again, thank you

Comment: If you're wondering, I imported tkinter and it magically worked